# How to use variable from another class?

Tags: java

I am creating a maze game. For that I have created 4 separate class files. I'd like to know how I can access the inmates of Maze.class in Player.class move() method and not just read it but also add to it and overwrite it:

Maze.class

```
package y1;

import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings(value = "all")

public class Maze {
private Room entry;
private Map <Room, ArrayList<Player>> inmates=new HashMap<Room,ArrayList<Player>>();
/**
 * 
 * @param r The room that is going to be the entry
 */
public void setEntry(Room r){
    this.entry=r;
    }
/**
 * 
 * @return Returns the entry room
 */
    public Room getEntry(){
        return this.entry;
    }
    /**
     * Method adds a player to the maze
    * @param p Player to be added to the maze
    */
    public void addPlayer(Player p){
        ArrayList<Player> players=new ArrayList<Player>();
        p.setRoom(getEntry());
        if (this.inmates.isEmpty()==true){
        players.add(p);
        this.inmates.put(this.entry,players);
        }
        else{
        players=this.inmates.get(this.entry);
        players.add(p);
        }

        this.inmates.put(p.getRoom(), players);

    }
    public void getPlayers(Room r){
        if(this.inmates.get(r)!=null){
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(this.inmates.get(r)));
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("Ruum on tühi");

        }
    }
    public Map getInmates(){
        return this.inmates;
    }
}
```

Room.class

```
package y1;

import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings(value = "all")
public class Room {

private String name;
private Room north;
private Room east;
private Room west;
private Room south;
private boolean isExit = false;
private boolean isPortal = false;
private Maze maze;

/**
 * @return Returns the name of the room
 */
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

/**
 * Sets room name
 * 
 * @param name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Gets northern room if any
 * 
 * @return pointer to northern room if any, otherwise <code>null</code>
 */
public Room getNorth() {
    return this.north;
}

/**
 * Sets the door to the next room to the north in that room and in the other
 * room sets southern door as connecting back to that room
 * 
 * @param otherRoom
 */
public void setNorth(Room otherRoom) {
    this.north = otherRoom;
    otherRoom.south = this;
}
public Room getSouth() {
    return this.south;
}

/**
 * Sets the door to the next room to the south in that room and in the other
 * room sets northern door as connecting back to that room
 * 
 * @param otherRoom
 */
public void setSouth(Room otherRoom) {
    this.south = otherRoom;
    otherRoom.north = this;
}
public Room getEast() {
    return this.east;
}

/**
 * Sets the door to the next room to the east in that room and in the other
 * room sets western door as connecting back to that room
 * 
 * @param otherRoom
 */
public void setEast(Room otherRoom) {
    this.east = otherRoom;
    otherRoom.west = this;
}
public Room getWest() {
    return this.west;
}

/**
 * Sets the door to the next room to the west in that room and in the other
 * room sets eastern door as connecting back to that room
 * 
 * @param otherRoom
 */
public void setWest(Room otherRoom) {
    this.west = otherRoom;
    otherRoom.east = this;
}
/**
 * Returns the room in the given direction
 * 
 * @param Which way to move?
 * @return The room in that direction.
 */
public Room get(String direction){
    Room dir=this;
    if(direction=="N" && this.north!=null){
        dir=dir.getNorth();
        return dir;
    }
    else if(direction=="W" && this.west!=null){
        dir=dir.getWest();
        return dir;
    }
    else if(direction=="E" && this.east!=null){
        dir=dir.getEast();
        return dir;
    }
    else if(direction=="S" && this.south!=null){
        dir=dir.getSouth();
        return dir;
    }
    else{
        return dir;
    }


}
/**
 * Returns the room that givens coordinates point to
 * 
 * @param dirlist List of directions
 * @return returns Returns the room it stops in
 */
public Room get(List<String> dirlist){
    Room dir=this;
    if (validate(dirlist)==true){
        for(int i=0;i<dirlist.size();i++){
            if(dirlist.get(i)=="N"){
                dir=dir.getNorth();
            }
            else if(dirlist.get(i)=="W"){
                dir=dir.getWest();
            }
            else if(dirlist.get(i)=="E"){
                dir=dir.getEast();
            }
            else if(dirlist.get(i)=="S"){
                dir=dir.getSouth();
            }
        }
    }
    return dir;     
}


/**
 * creates a new room to the north and connects back to this room
 * 
 * @param toa nimi
 *            0
 * @return uus tuba
 */
public Room createNorth(String name) {
    Room otherRoom = null;

    // Creates new room only when no room lies ahead in this direction
    if (this.getNorth() == null) { // Checks north - if nothing there then new room is create
        otherRoom = new Room(); // Creates new room
        this.setNorth(otherRoom); // Creates door between rooms
        otherRoom.setName(name); // Names the room

    } else { // If room already exists then prints alert message
        System.out.println("Room already exist!");
    }

    return otherRoom;
}
public Room createSouth(String name) {
    Room otherRoom = null;
    if (this.getSouth() == null) {
        otherRoom = new Room();
        this.setSouth(otherRoom); 
        otherRoom.setName(name);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Room already exists!");
    }

    return otherRoom;
}
public Room createEast(String name) {
    Room otherRoom = null;
    if (this.getEast() == null) {
        otherRoom = new Room();
        this.setEast(otherRoom);
        otherRoom.setName(name);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Room already exists!");
    }

    return otherRoom;
}
public Room createWest(String name) {
    Room otherRoom = null;
    if (this.getWest() == null) {
        otherRoom = new Room();
        this.setWest(otherRoom);
        otherRoom.setName(name);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Room already exists!");
    }

    return otherRoom;
}
public void setExit(){
    this.isExit=true;
}

public void setPortalA(){
    this.isPortal=true;
}
public boolean validate(List<String> pathList){
    Room check = this;
    boolean value=false;
    for(int i = 0;i<pathList.size();i++){
        if(pathList.get(i)=="N" && check.north!=null){
            check=check.north;
            value=true;
        }
        else if(pathList.get(i)=="S" && check.south!=null){
            check=check.south;
            value=true;
        }
        else if(pathList.get(i)=="W" && check.west!=null){
            check=check.west;
            value=true;
        }
        else if(pathList.get(i)=="E" && check.east!=null){
            check=check.east;
            value=true;
        }
        else{ 
            value = false;
            System.out.println("Can't move in the given directions!");
        }
    }
    return value;       
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getName();
}
```

}

and Player.class

```
package y1;

import java.util.*;

public class Player {
private String name;
private Room location;

public void setRoom(Room r){
    this.location=r;
}
public Room getRoom(){
    System.out.println(this.name+" is at " +this.location);
    return this.location;

}


public Room move(String dir){
    Player p=this;
    if(dir=="N" && this.location.getNorth()!=null){
        p.location=p.location.getNorth();
    }
    else if(dir=="S" && this.location.getSouth()!=null){
        p.location=p.location.getSouth();
    }
    else if(dir=="W" && this.location.getWest()!=null){
        p.location=p.location.getWest();
    }
    else if(dir=="E" && this.location.getEast()!=null){
        p.location=p.location.getEast();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("There's a wall in the way!");
    }
    return this.location;   
}
public Room move(List<String> dirList){
    Player player=this;
        for(int i=0 ; i<dirList.size() ; i++){
            if(dirList.get(i)=="N" && player.location.getNorth()!=null){
                player.location=player.location.getNorth();
            }
            else if(dirList.get(i)=="S" && player.location.getSouth()!=null){
                player.location=player.location.getSouth();
            }
            else if(dirList.get(i)=="W" && player.location.getWest()!=null){
                player.location=player.location.getWest();
            }
            else if(dirList.get(i)=="E" && player.location.getEast()!=null){
                player.location=player.location.getEast();
            }   
            else{
                System.out.println("Wall in the way. Stopping!");
                break;
            }
        }
    return this.location;   
}

public void setName(String n){
    this.name=n;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player needs to have a reference in some way to the Maze object in order to call the getInmates() method (or any other modifier method) on it.

How you get the reference is up to you, and there are many ways to do it. One way would be to have the Player's location (Room object) provide the reference. To do that, you could implement a getMaze() method in the Room object that would return that Room's Maze. In the move() method of Player, you could call getMaze() on the Player's 'location' property (which is a Room), and then call getInmates() on the returned Maze object.

After that, it's just how you want to implement the modifier/reset methods on the Maze object.

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution I was looking for! Can't believe it was right in front of me. I kind of thought that I don't have to deal with Room class anymore. But seems like there's no escape :D

Comment: I thought it through and realized that the best way for me would be by assigning the Player another location property called "mazeloc" or something like that. And it will be initialized when addPlayer() method is used. This property shows which maze the player currently is in.

Comment: @Rauno, that works, however, it might not the best way in terms of "proper" design. The problem is that you're introducing more "bookkeeping" by doing that: now you need to update 'mazeloc' in addition to 'location' every time the Player moves.

Comment: Well actually not. Mazeloc is just for keeping the info about which maze the player currently is in. It only changes when the player exits maze and enters another one.

Comment: Ah. Still, it's an extra property to keep track of that can be derived without much effort from existing properties. For instance, perhaps you split your Maze into different sub-Mazes. Each time the player moves a location, they need to check if the Maze they are in has changed, and update their 'mazeloc'. An easier way to do it would be to make a getMaze() method for Player to call on itself that returns the Maze its current Room is in.

Comment: **OR** if you're only going to concern yourself with one Maze in the entire game, you may want to look into the "Singleton" design pattern for the Maze class, and use a statically referenced Maze object.

Comment: Well either way I have to create a new property. In your case it would be in Room class in my case it is in Player class.

Comment: Your Room class already has a 'maze' property. You would need an accessor, yes, but the data is already there (although, it looks like it's never referenced).

Comment: How can I access that unreferenced data?

Comment: In leu of the **Please avoid extended discussions in comments.** I'd request you look into everything we've discussed for an answer to that. Also, if this all has answered your original question, I'd very much appreciate this answer marked as accepted :) If you have more questions, I'd suggest doing some more research, and opening another question if need be.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create modifier methods, e.g.

```
public void resetInmates(){
    this.inmates = new Map();
}

public void addInmate( Room r, ArrayList<Player> players ){
}

public void removeInmate( Room r ){
}
```

etc

Comment: Yup, probably better than a getter method, depends a bit on how much access is needed by the other classes.

Comment: Note that you might not want to expose those methods using `public`. Package visibility should be enough if those methods are not meant for access outside of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `private` from the inmates field makes it readable for other classes in the same package, but it would be good design to creata a getter method (possibly also package visible) instead.

Comment: that is a very bad practice; other classes should not need to worry about the details of how `inmates` are implemented and how to read/access/modify them

Comment: True, but it does answer the question. Besides, if it is hidden inside a package and not exposed to the outside, it might have its merrits. I've already mentioned that the answer of scibuff is better.